# Reload current function after time withouth reload page

Tags: jquery

If possible, I'd like to reload a jQuery `prototype`/`function` after a delay without refresh all the page.

```
my.prototype.reloadMe = function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
      my.reloadMe();
    },1000);
    alert('ok');
};
```

I tried with a `setTimeout` in the function but it didn't work: it refreshs only one time.

Thanks for your suggestions or explanations.

Comment: Can you show us your `setTimeout` try?

Comment: `setTimeout` is what you want. "but id didn't work" - try to investigate it. What happened? Any errors in console?

Comment: I've edited my post. Thanks

Comment: `reload a jQuery prototype/function` What do you mean exactly? I guess your issue is not regarding redefining a protoype method but more regarding what is doing this method. Sounds like XY problem to me. And regarding your posted code, firstly it is `setTimeout` not `setTimeOut`. Secondly, this code doesn't make sense regarding your question

Comment: Your code totally changes the situation. I'm going to try to create a nice answer but `setTimeout` is not your only problem.

Comment: Ok so rereading question, i guess by `reload` you mean call method recursively instead, following some delay. I misunderstood your question, my bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you define a **prototype** function, and then you try to call it as an object function. You should get an error like "`my.reloadMe()` is not a function".

```
my.prototype.reloadMe = function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
      my.reloadMe(); // "my" object does not contain "reloadMe" function 
    },1000);
    alert('ok');
};
```

If you want to access this function, you can either call this prototype function explicitly:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  my.prototype.reloadMe();
}, 1000);
```

or instantiate your object and call this function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  new my().reloadMe();
}, 1000);
```

which both do not sound correct.

It looks like the best solution is to name your anonymous function:

```
my.prototype.reloadMe = function reload() {
    setTimeout(reload, 1000);
    alert('ok');
};);
```

**Note 1:** in your code you use `setTimeOut`, while it is `setTimeout`. JS is case-sensitive. Perhaps, it can be a source of the error.

**Note 2:** any of this code will make it run in an infinite loop. So, actually, you will get an alert every second. I hope that it is exactly what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's became clear. Problem solved! :)

Answer (score 2):

It should be `this.reloadMe` to get the correct instance.

```
my.prototype.reloadMe = function () {
    var that = this;

    setTimeOut(function(){
        that.reloadMe();
    }, 1000);

    alert('ok');
};
```

But this would be an endless loop. You have to break this if you only want it once to be called again.

```
my.prototype.reloadMe = function () {
    var that = this;

    if( !that.delayedCalled ) {
        setTimeOut(function() {
            that.delayedCalled = true;
            that.reloadMe();
        }, 1000);
    }

    alert('ok');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Create your object:

function myobject(){
  
}

//add prototype to that object

myobject.prototype.reloadMe = function(){
  
  // instead of recursion you can use interval
  
  setInterval(function () {
    alert('ok');
  }, 1000);
}

// instantiate that object

var my = new myobject();

//call your function

my.reloadMe();
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand better now :)